# How to write V-IF in TR with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have this code.

```
<tr class='uatabledata' v-bind:id=item.id>
```

My search code:

```
function changeStatus(obj) {
  var StatusCode = obj.value;
  $('#StatusSearch').val(StatusCode).trigger('keyup');
}
```

If work `changeStatus` function, I want my `<tr>` element to change. I want `v-if`.

```
<tr class='uatabledata' v-if="item.invoiceNo != ''" v-bind:id=item.id>
```

I have 3 status code and 1 invoice number. If invoice number is `null` it's not showing.

*I'm so sorry for bad english.*

Comment: Could you post more of your code? I'm having a hard time understanding the issue. `v-if` will prevent the element from rendering if the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: [Why not to use jQuery in a JavaScript Framework](https://dev.to/darkknight/why-not-to-use-jquery-in-a-javascript-framework-497f)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: Tried to fix some issues.